# How did my Google chrome extensions got automatically deleted?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So, this is what it happened, I was at my college using my laptop at it's last stage of power coz i forgot the charger at home. So i closed the lid. Put the laptop in bag and came home, astonished to find that the laptop was switched off.(Not hibernated) Then i opened chrome and was using it and suddenly i saw ads. And quickly checked my extensions and found that all of my extensions had disappeared. with a message "Boo... You have no extensions :-("

Any idea how i could restore the extensions back? I don't even remember the name of all extensions. I read somewhere that logging into Google account will re-sync the extensions. But i just realized that the last time i logged into chrome using Google account was a year ago.

I suspect it's some bug of Chrome.
Any ideas? Suggestions? Please!

Comment: What OS are you using? You might be able to recover data from your profile directory. This question is off-topic for this site though, try our sister site http://superuser.com/.

Comment: I'm using Win-7 64 bit.
And Google Chrome version 30.0.1599.101 m It's the latest version. How do i recover data from profile directory?

Comment: Take a look at `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Default`, and check whether it exists.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could try logging in with your Google account. Perhaps you were logged in to Chrome, and it somehow logged out.

Also it's quite a known issue, check: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142059

Comment: Dude, following that link and doing what it said made me lose everything from chrome including bookmarks, history everything!! :(

Answer (score -1):

Easy fix - just reinstall any one of your previous extensions and the rest will all reappear as they are cached at Google.

Answer (score -1):

If you were logged in with your Google account, just open https://chrome.google.com/webstore/user/library